# Unable to start crop activity (using github.com/lvillani/android-cropimage ) Library

Tags: java, android

I use the Library:
https://github.com/lvillani/android-cropimage
for adding  crop activity in my project.I import this library and add in my project now I am writing this code :

```
 String mPackage = "com.android.camera";
 String mClass = ".CropImage";
 intent.setComponent(new ComponentName(mPackage,mPackage+mClass));
 startActivityForResult(intent, CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);
```

It gives error :
Unable to find explicit activity class {com.android.camera/com.android.camera.CropImage}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?

I tried to write in AndroidManifest.xml in my project ass well but still the same error.

Answer (score 3):

Step #1: Add an `<activity>` element to your manifest pointing to `com.android.camera.CropImage`

Step #2: Use `new Intent(this, com.android.camera.CropImage.class)` to create your `Intent`

Step #3: There should be no step #3 AFAIK

Comment: Not running still gives same error:( listen friend I want to capture an image and after that I wanted to run this crop activity (Note that this was the feature of previous version Android API which was eliminated in 2.x.

Comment: that guy lvillani extract the classes of previous version API and make a library project so we people can use this feature ...

Comment: @user672560: "Not running still gives same error" -- then you did not follow my instructions, or you decided to name your own app `com.android.camera`. If the latter, change it, as you cannot replace the built-in firmware's app, anyway. If your app has some other package, then if you followed my instructions, it is impossible for you to get an error about `com.android.camera/com.android.camera.CropImage`.

Comment: In Step 1 tell me where do i add activity element in android-cropimage Library Manifest file or in my own application manifest file ?

Comment: First of all in step two new Intent(this, com.android.camera.CropImage.class) it keeps giving me error due to "this" keyword so i tried getApplicationContext();(no error in compile time but activity not found error at runtime )  and also MyActivityClass.this (works at compile time but at runtime no Activity found error ) :(

Comment: Ok i added in my own application  manifest but still gives same error :(

Comment: @user672560: If you left in the `setComponent()` call, delete it.

Comment: I m waiting for ur help CommonsWare :(

Comment: I have given u the link of my activity mainmenu class where i am calling it Please mention there , there are two button in my app one take pic from camera and other take pic from gallery Its user choice to slect the image then after that i want to allow crop feature ... please mention the code here  from my java class what do i do..

Answer (score 1):

Add activity like this in your android manifest file,

```
...
....
</activity>
        <!-- Declare the bundled CropImage Activity -->
        <activity android:name="com.android.camera.CropImage"/>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Documentation indeed helps :) [link](https://github.com/lvillani/android-cropimage/blob/master/CropImageRepo/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml)